# Cannot decode russian symbols in pdf (xhtml2pdf)

Tags: django, xhtml2pdf

Following [this](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/), I've created html to pdf converter and it works fine with english language, but I have some russian symbols that I cannot decode. Instead of normal russian words I get:

```
Ñ‚ÑƒÑ‚ Ð´Ð¾Ð»Ð¶ÐµÐ½ Ð±Ñ‹Ñ‚ÑŒ Ñ‚ÐµÐºÑ■Ñ
```

template:

```
<html lang="ru">

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>MC-report</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="align:center"> тут должен быть текст {{ today }}</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have same code *(plus some code just to get needed data*) as in this manual, instead of playing with html.encode and template:

```
pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result) #for decoding data, not template text
```

None of cp1251/2/866 and UTF-8 won't work

Answer (score 1):

add to your html   (Alice-Regular.ttf) is Russian fonts

```
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />



    <style>
        @font-face {
        font-family: "Alice-Regular";
        src: url("/fonts/Alice-Regular.ttf") format("truetype");
        }

        body {
        font-family: "Alice-Regular";
        font-size: 20px
        }
    </style>
```